# How can i do pagination and searching in YII?

Tags: php, yii, pagination

Here is my controller code for displaying..

```
  $this->layout = 'admin-home';
             $studios = AccountsStudios::model()->with('generalUserStudiosesCount')->findAll();

             #print_r($studios);
             $this->render('listStudios', array('studios' => $studios));
```

Am entirely new to YII... i want to include filter option,search and pagination .

Any good references?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/25901-pagination-solution-simple-and-complex-ways/

Comment: @redGREENblue pagination done..wat abt filtering /searching

Comment: I have checked that link. How ever how would I do pagination based on an array of string values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CGridView displays a list of data items in terms of a table.

Each row of the table represents the data of a single data item, and a column usually represents an attribute of the item (some columns may correspond to complex expression of attributes or static text).

CGridView supports both sorting and pagination of the data items. The sorting and pagination can be done in AJAX mode or normal page request. A benefit of using CGridView is that when the user browser disables JavaScript, the sorting and pagination automatically degenerate to normal page requests and are still functioning as expected.
[CLick Here to get more deatls](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView)